# Matlab code to auto crop the black borders in a video frame that appear after stabilization of the video?

Tags: matlab, video

I have developed a code to stabilize a shaky video. However after stabilization the video frames  have black borders around it which is very annoying to watch. 
Can you please suggest how to auto crop them?

Comment: Check out my post where I helped someone implement auto-cropping black borders of images.  Be warned that this only works in certain situations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584353/matlab-improve-code-in-image-cropping-black-border/25584581#25584581

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you use imregtform or imregister to stabilize your videos? If so you could (in case @rayryeng's solution does not work) use the tform vectors to get the displacement in each direction and so crop your images accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

this helped me may be it can help u out too
http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/128133-automatically-trim-remove-crop-black-borders-margins-from-images-volumes

Comment: please conclude some important and post it in answer too.