# Crop black artifacts from stabilized video

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing, artifacts

I have a video that I need to stabilize with matlab.
I managed to get a stabilized video, but it has some black artifacts on the frame edges (an example can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMaCjQ8-WY0) - it's not my video but has the same problem).

Is there an efficient way to get a final video without those artifacts?
I  thought about cropping every frame to the same size, but to know that size one must process the whole video in order to know the maximal "penetration" of those artifacts.

I examined some frames individually and I noticed that the artifacts are pure black (i.e the intensity level is 0), if that makes it a little bit easier.

thanks.

Comment: Cropping seems a good idea to me. If you want to know the exact maximal penetration, you should indeed process the whole video first. As an alternative you may use a fixed penetration based on your prior knowledge of the movie(s) you are dealing with. I suggest you to give it a try.

Comment: Yes, in order to know the size, you need to see the whole video, there is no around it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone might find it useful sometime - I came up with this implementation (solution is mainly based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584581/5462551) answer (the last part), which was answered to a similar question regarding a single image...):

```
function [] = stabilizeVideo(fileName)

    % open video reader and writer
    InputVid = vision.VideoFileReader(fileName);
    StabilizedVid = vision.VideoFileWriter('StabilizedVidWithArtifacts.avi');


    leftPent = 0;
    upPent = 0;
    [downPent, rightPent] = size(imgB);

    % any initialization you might need...

    while ~isDone(InputVid)
        % Stabilize frame... the warped frame is called 'imgBp'
        % write the warped frame to the video
        step(StabilizedVid,imgBp);

        % now the magic happens:    
        [up, down, left, right] = FindMaxArtifactPenetration(imgBp);
        leftPent = max(left, leftPent);
        rightPent = min(right, rightPent);
        upPent = max(up, upPent);
        downPent = min(down, downPent);        

    end
    release(InputVid);
    release(StabilizedVid);
    cropArtifacts(upPent, downPent, leftPent, rightPent);
    display(num2str(toc));
end
```

I wrote those helper functions:

```
function [up, down, left, right] = FindMaxArtifactPenetration(I)
    % allow RGB or grayscale image
    if size(I,3)==3
        I1 = rgb2gray(I);
    else
        I1 = I;
    end

    nonZeroCols = find(any(I1)); % find non-zero cols
    left = min(nonZeroCols); 
    right = max(nonZeroCols); 
    I2 = I1(:, left : right, :);
    nonZeroRows = find(any(I2, 2)); % find non-zero rows
    up = min(nonZeroRows); 
    down = max(nonZeroRows);
end

function [] = cropArtifacts(minRow, maxRow, minCol, maxCol)

    % reload video with artifacts, crop every frame and save it in the 
    % new video
    InputVid = vision.VideoFileReader('StabilizedVidWithArtifacts.avi');
    StabilizedVid = vision.VideoFileWriter('StabilizedVid.avi');
    while ~isDone(InputVid)
        frame = step(InputVid);
        step(StabilizedVid, frame(minRow:maxRow, minCol:maxCol, :));
    end
    release(InputVid);
    release(StabilizedVid);

end
```